# JavaScript load list of images from Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load images in list of object from Ajax results.

```
$('#div-images').empty();
for (var key in data.listImage) {
  var mi = data.listImage[key];
  var image_url = mi.IMAGE_URL;
  var image_tag = '<img id=image' + key + ' width="50" height="50" />';
  $('#div-images').append(image_tag);

  // load image
  var _img = document.getElementById('image' + key);
  var newImg = new Image;
  newImg.onload = function() {
    _img.src = this.src;
  }
  newImg.src = image_url;
}
```

But the code above only load the latest image on the list. Please tell me the right syntax how to do this on the loop process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

update statement like

```
  newImg.key = key;
  newImg.onload = function() {
    var _img = document.getElementById('image' + this.key);
    _img.src = this.src;
  }
```

```js
$('#div-images').empty();
var data = {
 listImage: [
 {IMAGE_URL: "http://www.wordapp.io/wpsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google-ranking-factors.png"},
 {IMAGE_URL: "http://pukdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/googles-new-logo-5078286822539264.3-hp2x.gif"}
 ]
}
for (var key in data.listImage) {
  var mi = data.listImage[key];
  var image_url = mi.IMAGE_URL;
  var image_tag = '<img id=image' + key + ' width="50" height="50" />';
  $('#div-images').append(image_tag);

  // load image  
  var newImg = new Image(key);
  newImg.key = key;
  newImg.onload = function() {
    var _img = document.getElementById('image' + this.key);
    _img.src = this.src;
  }
  newImg.src = image_url;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div-images"></div>
```